# Asp.net mvc 5 SendGrid not confirming Email upon click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was following the "Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)" from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)
I had a hard time setting up the SendGrid Api since i am new to this...
But somehow i got it work to sent me a confirmation email... The Problem is that when i click on the confirmation link it throws me An error occurred while processing your request. Error...***

[image]

So this is how i configure SendGrid in the **IdentityConfig.cs**

```
 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
         public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
                {
                    sendMail(message);
                });
            }
        async void sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
        {
           // var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridKey"];
            var apiKey = "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";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
            myMessage.From = new EmailAddress("bubulubu001@gmail.com","Angelito");
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
            await client.SendEmailAsync(myMessage);
        }
    }
```

**i also runned the application in debug mode, and add it a break point to the Register Method and ConfirmEmail Method. In the ConfirmEmail Method i got this Error. i am guessing it has to be something with the Token..."**

[image]

**If Anyone could help me fix this i would really apreciated...
Also if you guys could recommend latest books to Become a pro at asp.net or core. i would much apreciated.**

So i made the changes to the code... Am still receiving the the confirmation link on my Email but when i click on it get invalidToken if i add a break point to ConfirmEmail Method...

[image]

Comment: The code is wrong. You shouldn't be using `async void` or using `Task.Factory.StartNew. Replace all the code inside `SendAsync` with the code from `sendMail`

Comment: I addapted the code from the microsoft docs tutorial and following your advice... but still no luck having a successfull link confirmation.

Comment: The docs don't need adapting. Nor do they show what you posted. There's no `client.SendEmailAsync` in that example.  The docs show how to hook up Sendgrid as the default Identity email service and then use `UserManager.SendEmailAsync` to send a confirmation email using that default email service

Comment: As for `when i click on the confirmation link it throws me` this has nothing to do with SendGrid. If the link is wrong, it won't work.

Comment: Does the link point to *localhost*? That link will try to connect to a site running on the end user's machine on port 44337. This won't even work on your own machine unless the correct project is running when you click on the link

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the code. You shouldn't be using `async void` or using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. `async void` is *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers and can't be awaited.

Since `SendEmailAsync` is asynchronous, there's no reason to run it into another task. Even if there was a reason to start another task, `Task.Run` should be used, not `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

The code should change to :

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    await sendMailAsync(message);
}

async Task sendMailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    ...
    await client.SendEmailAsync(myMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, :3 Your answer helped me resolve this issue. :3 Pass the books xD

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is what the code looks like inside IdentityConfig.cs
in order to send an Email confirmation and to confirm it in your inbox. The following code worked for me. The rest is the same as the Microsoft.docs

**IdentityConfig.cs**

```
     public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
        }
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var apiKey = "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";
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("bubulubu001@gmail.com","Angel" );
        var subject = message.Subject;
        var to = new EmailAddress(message.Destination);
        var plainTextContent = message.Body;
        var htmlContent = message.Body;
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent,htmlContent);

        // Send the email.
        if (client != null)
        {
            await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```